# ObjectMapper - Best practice for thread-safety and performance

Tags: java, json, performance, thread-safety, jackson-databind

### Summary

I want to find the best practice for using `ObjectMapper` and/or `ObjectReader` in terms of thread-safety and performance in the context of the use-case described below.

### Background

I have a helper class (**Json.java**) where the method `toObject()` uses `ObjectMapper` to translate from a `json` string to an object of a given (json-mappable) class.

### Problem / question

I have read that `ObjectReader` is often recommended for being fully thread-safe, but I mostly see it being in a non-generic context where the class to read for is predefined. In this context, what do you believe to be the best practice in terms of thread-safety and performance? In the code I have three suggestions that I could think of as a starting point.

I have tried to look at through the source code and docs for `jackson-databind`, but my theoretical Java skills are not good enough to derive an answer from them. I have also looked at similar questions on SO and elsewhere, but haven't found any that match my case closely enough.

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader;

public abstract class Json {

    private static final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    // NOTE: jsonReader is only relevant for Suggestion 3.
    private static final ObjectReader jsonReader = jsonMapper.reader(); 

    // Suggestion 1:
    public static <T> T toObject1(final Class<T> type, final String json) throws IOException {
        return jsonMapper.readValue(json, type);
    }

    // Suggestion 2:
    public static <T> T toObject2(final Class<T> type, final String json) throws IOException {
        return jsonMapper.readerFor(type).readValue(json);
    }

    // Suggestion 3:
    public static <T> T toObject3(final Class<T> type, final String json) throws IOException {
        return jsonReader.forType(type).readValue(json);
    }

    // Remainder of class omitted for brevity.
}
```

Comment: I have always used suggestion #1. This lets the mapper sort out the best way to perform de-serialization

Comment: @SharonBenAsher why? how does it make a difference?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
private static final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Constructing an `ObjectMapper` instance is a relatively expensive operation, so it's recommended to create one object and reuse it. You did it right making it `final`.

```
// Suggestion 1:
public static <T> T toObject1(final Class<T> type, final String json) throws IOException {
    return jsonMapper.readValue(json, type);
}
```

You always **read** JSON to a POJO, so let's be precise and clear, and use `ObjectReader`.

```
// Suggestion 2:
public static <T> T toObject2(final Class<T> type, final String json) throws IOException {
    return jsonMapper.readerFor(type).readValue(json);
}

// Suggestion 3:
public static <T> T toObject3(final Class<T> type, final String json) throws IOException {
    return jsonReader.forType(type).readValue(json);
}
```

There is no difference, really. Both methods will construct a new `ObjectReader` object: the former (`jsonMapper.readerFor(type)`) will give you a fully-built instance directly, the latter (`jsonReader.forType(type)`) will complement the not-yet-usable `jsonReader` and returns a ready-to-use object. I would rather go with option 2 because I don't want to keep that field.

You shouldn't worry about performance or thread-safety. Even though creating an `ObjectMapper` might be costly (or making a copy out of it), getting and working with `ObjectReader`s is lightweight and completely thread-safe.

From [the Java documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html) (emphasis mine):

> Uses "mutant factory" pattern so that instances are **immutable** (and thus **fully thread-safe with no external synchronization**); new instances are constructed for different configurations. Instances are initially constructed by `ObjectMapper` and can be reused, shared, cached; both because of thread-safety and because instances are **relatively light-weight**.

I recently had these questions myself and decided on `ObjectMapper#reader(InjectableValues)` as a factory method. It's very handy particularly when you want to customise an `ObjectReader` slightly or, as it was in my case, to adjust a `DeserializationContext`.

That's an excellent question, by the way.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer! Your recommendation differs from those given by @davidxxx and Sharon Ben Asher, but it seems like you have really done your research here so I'm inclined to believe you.

Comment: @axeleration their points are good, and I think either option is fine (performant/thread-safe)

Answer (score 5):

**About concurrency**

`ObjectMapper` versus `ObjectReader` is not relevant here.
The `ObjectReader` doesn't look to be helpful for your scenario.
Its specification says :

> Builder object that can be used for per-serialization configuration of
>   deserialization parameters, such as root type to use or object to
>   update (instead of constructing new instance).

Note that both instances of `ObjectMapper` and `ObjectReader` are thread safe provided that their configuration is not changed between serialization/deserialization client calls.
The `ObjectReader` specified indeed :

> Mapper instances are fully thread-safe provided that ALL configuration
>   of the instance occurs before ANY read or write calls.

While `ObjectReader` has as difference to be immutable in the way where updating its configuration will make it return a new instance of as stated by its documentation :

> Uses "mutant factory" pattern so that instances are immutable (and
>   thus fully thread-safe with no external synchronization); new
>   instances are constructed for different configurations.

In your requirement, you don't want to change the configuration between client calls. So using `ObjectMapper` looks more relevant.
So I would eliminate the 3) way and also the 2) way since  `jsonMapper.readerFor(type)` that is factory method for `ObjectReader` instance.  Still you don't matter to use an `ObjectReader` here.

So the simplest and common way looks better :

```
// Suggestion 1:
public static <T> T toObject1(final Class<T> type, final String json) throws IOException {
    return jsonMapper.readValue(json, type);
 }
```

**About performance**

Besides, remember `ObjectReader` is immutable. So the 2 and 3 ways create new instances of `ObjectReader` at each call. 
It  doesn't look a good hint for performance.
Yes, these are lightweight objects but creating them at each time has a cost.
The `ObjectReader` doc says :

> Instances are initially constructed by ObjectMapper and can be reused,
>   shared, cached; both because of thread-safety and because instances
>   are relatively light-weight.

There you don't reuse these instances. So you lose any benefit in terms of caching and of performance.
You could store them into a `Map` field and reuse them but do it only if you need to improve the actual performance of `ObjectMapper` and of course measure before concluding anything.

Conclusion : for your use case, I think that performance as well as concurrency is better with the first solution (`ObjectMapper`)

Comment: Great answer (I think)! So, essentially I should only be using ObjectReader if I want to apply different configurations for the different calls?

Comment: That may be also helpful for other cases. As the javadoc says : "Builder object that can be used for per-serialization configuration of deserialization parameters, such as root type to use or object to update (instead of constructing new instance)." For example `ObjectReader.withValueToUpdate(Object)` is a good reason to use that. ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005176/jackson-gson-apply-map-to-pojo Here you don't enter in this kind of scenarios.

Comment: @davidxxx I guess "Instances are initially constructed by ObjectMapper" means "you normally use an ObjectMapper to create instances". It doesn't imply an ObjectMapper internally manages (e.g. caches) these instances. As a matter of fact, I couldn't find `ObjectReader` stored in `ObjectMapper`...

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko Of course. And it would be undesirable. My point is that creating `ObjectReader` at each call has a cost since it is not cached. So in the current scenario, it looks unnecessary.

Comment: @davidxxx it would be quite desirable (for the same configuration), wouldn't it?

Comment: @davidxxx my point is `ObjectMapper` doesn't cache anything either. By "anything" I meant any instances of `ObjectReader\Writer`

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko  Of course but if both don't cache, what is the approach that looks more simple and efficient ?  Creating an `ObjectReader` at each call or reusing the `ObjectMapper` ?

Answer (score 4):

As I mention in the comment, I have always used suggestion #1. I have no knowledge if there is difference between the options in terms of thread safety/performance or at all.

However, this approach will **not** work if the target type is itself parameterized with generic type. The most obvious usage is some collection:

```
Json.toObject1(List.class, str);  // will deserialize into List<Object>
```

for this purpose you will have to use Jackson's [`TypeReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html)

```
// Suggestion 4:
public static <T> T toObject4(final TypeReference<T> typeRef, final String json) throws IOException {
    return jsonMapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
}

Json.toObject4(new TypeReference<List<SomeClass>>(){}, str);  // will deserialize into List<SomeClass>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was actually aware of the TypeReference case and had an overloaded toObject() for just that, but decided not to include it in the question for brevity.

To clarify, I don't believe thread-safety or performance will actually be significant in what I'm working on here, but I find the library fascinating and want to gain a better understanding of it.